# Typescript Class: Define dynamic properties and types based on generic type

Tags: typescript, class, dynamic, types

What the title says. The method where the properties are dynamically added to the class is

`private makeObservables(state: State): void`.

What I want more specifically to do is to be able to iterate through the types in the `State` type variable and map them to properties on the class (with types based on the ones in `State`), so that Typescript will know about them and will not complain.

```
class AbstractStore<State> {
  constructor(state: State) {
    this.makeObservables(state)
  }

  private makeObservables(state: State): void {
    const keys = Object.keys(state)
    keys.forEach(key => {
      this[`\$${key}`] = `\$observable for ${state[key]}`
    })
  }
}

interface UserState {
    name: string,
    color: string,
    lives: number
}

const state: UserState = {
    name: 'Mihai',
    color: 'blue',
    lives: 3
}

const store = new AbstractStore<UserState>(state)

console.log(store.$name)
console.log(store.$color)
console.log(store.$lives)
```

Currently **Typescript** gives me the following errors:

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AbstractStore'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AbstractStore'*

and

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.*

on this line

```
this[`\$${key}`] = `\$observable for ${state[key]}`
```

If I add this it's no good because then I won't be able to define methods on the class:

`[index: string]: string`

As a note, the code works and the output in the console is correct:

```
$observable for Mihai
$observable for blue
$observable for 3
```

Comment: TypeScript only exists at compile-time. After compilation, there is only JavaScript. There is no way for TypeScript to be aware of runtime values. If you want TypeScript to accept this code, you can add explicit `: any` types to let the compiler know to trust you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I've updated the title. I know typescript only exists at compile time, but given that all the dynamic properties I want to define are basd on an existing type (`UserState` in my example), passed as a generic, I think there should be a way to do this.

Comment: Ah; yes, that makes more sense here. I believe this is https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754, which is not currently possible. You want to be able to say something like `[K in keyof T].map((k) => '$' . k)`, and I don't believe TypeScript can express that. "Given an indexing string, generate another indexing string by applying a function."

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! Too bad is not possible yet... But thanks a lot for pointing me to that github thread and for better summarizing my question! I even found someone who wanted this feature for the exact same reason I wanted it :)